# PyMongo [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] on subsequent requests initiated from local app

Tags: reactjs, ssl, openssl, pymongo, fastapi

I have seen the questions on the error in the title and the suggestions has fixed the DB Connection issue, however, all the subsequent requests from a local React project still result in the same error...

(Previous suggestions that worked out and allows me to connect to mongodb: `tlsCAFile=certifi.where()` adding this to the mongo connection.)

Should I generate some kind of SSL certificate for local? How can I avoid passing SSL certificate (I don't even know if its possible to generate SSL for localhost...).

Full error: `{ "status": "error", "msg": "Fail to fetch data from the url, err: \"<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)>\"" }`

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing python certificates after adding `certifi.where()` solved the issue.

on mac: `applications > python 3.11 > run Install_Certificates.command`